# Kivy : My label text is not updating after adding screens

Tags: python, arduino, kivy

So I wanted to read data from my `Arduino` through `serial port`, and update the data I read to a label text to display. It is working when I only have simple code to just read and update, but when I add in the `ScreenManager` and `Screen`, it stops updating the text.

Eventually I will need to have different animation according to the data I received, this is more on a testing if this function works

Thanks in Advance!

Here's my entire code

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] ='gl'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (NumericProperty, StringProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty)
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


LabelBase.register(name='Sans',fn_regular="Sansation-Regular.ttf")

import serial

kivy = Builder.load_string("""
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<MyManager>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    OperationScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome'
        font_size: 40
        on_touch_up : app.root.current = 'operation'

    Label:
        text: 'dafault'
        font_size: 20
        pos: -200,-100
        id: data_label


<OperationScreen>:
    name: 'operation'
    Label:
        text: 'Youre in'
        font_size: 40
""")   

class OperationScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def Read(self,dt):
        Clock.unschedule(self.Read)
        data = arduino.readline()
        if data != '':
            self.ids.data_label.text = data
        Clock.schedule_once(self.Read)
    pass

class MyManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class mainApp(App):
    Main = MainScreen()
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.Main.Read)
        return MyManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
    except:
        print("failed to connect")
    mainApp().run()
```

I expect the label with text 'default' to be changing accordingly but it just froze with the 'default'

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

When your app runs, there are two instances of `class MainScreen`. One was instantiated in kv file. The other one was instantiated manually, `Main = MainScreen()` in `class mainApp`.

The scheduling of method `Read()` is in the instance created manually, `Main = MainScreen()` and there is no modal view associated with this one.

## Solution

- In kv file, add `id: main_screen` for `MainScreen:`
- Remove `Main = MainScreen()` in `class mainApp`
- Implement a constructor for `class MyManager()`
- Move the scheduling from `class mainApp` into the constructor of `class MyManager()`
- In your case, it is better to use `Clock.create_trigger()` instead of `Clock.schedule_once()`
- The correct way to cancel a Clock event is either `event.cancel()` or `Clock.unschedule(event)`

## Example

### main.py

```
import os

os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import (NumericProperty, StringProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty)
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

# LabelBase.register(name='Sans', fn_regular="Sansation-Regular.ttf")

import serial

kivy = Builder.load_string("""
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<MyManager>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
    OperationScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome'
        font_size: 40
        on_touch_up : app.root.current = 'operation'

    Label:
        text: 'dafault'
        font_size: 20
        pos: -200,-100
        id: data_label


<OperationScreen>:
    name: 'operation'
    Label:
        text: 'Youre in'
        font_size: 40
""")


class OperationScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def Read(self, dt):
        data = str(dt)
        # data = arduino.readline()
        if data != '':
            self.ids.data_label.text = data
            self.manager.event_trigger()
        else:
            self.manager.event_trigger.cancel()


class MyManager(ScreenManager):
    event_trigger = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.event_trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.ids.main_screen.Read)
        self.event_trigger()


class mainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # try:
    #     arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
    # except:
    #     print("failed to connect")
    mainApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Would you mind telling me abit about when shall we use `def __init__(self, **kwargs):` and `super(MyManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)`

Comment: Implement a constructor `__init__()` whenever you want something to be done once 
 during instantiation. For example initialize class attributes, receive arguments passed from the caller, create event trigger etc.

Comment: Please remember to accept and/or up-vote the answer. Thank you.